# Problems understanding how to initialize an Object-c object in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I found this amazing TabBar at github called [FoldingTabBar.iOS](https://github.com/Yalantis/FoldingTabBar.iOS) and I already import and I am able to call and use but there is this initializer that I don't know how to use in swift and I really hope someone can help me, in the sample project hey call in the AppDelegate.m

**Object-C from example:**

```
YALFoldingTabBarController *tabBarController = (YALFoldingTabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;
```

When I try to create the YALFoldingTabBarController in my AppDelegate I have the options:

**What I try in Swift:**

```
YALFoldingTabBarController()
YALFoldingTabBarController(coder: NSCoder)
YALFoldingTabBarController(nib: String bunble:NSBundle) 
(sorry this is coming from memory so my be slightly wrong, but they are the default initializers for UIViewController)
```

I try

var controller = YALFoldingTabBarController()
controller = self.window.rootViewController as! YALFoldingTabBarController
Error cannot convert

```
var controller = YALFoldingTabBarController(self.window.rootViewController)
No such initializer
```

Any ideas how I go from the original Object-C initializer to a Swift one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the object is already initialized as the `rootViewController` according to your first line, so you shouldn't need to initialize but just set it to a variable. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Sorry my first line is the object-c example it does not work in Swift. I think I need to setup rootViewController to be of type YALFoldingTabBarController what is not at the moment is of type tabViewController

Comment: I think you'll need to change the class of the root controller in the storyboard to `YALFoldingTabBarController`.

Comment: I try to change to a whole class that inherit from YALFoldingTabBarController and do all the setting and didn't work but I didn't try to pure YALFoldingTabBarController see how it go

Comment: Please don't type code from memory that you're asking for debugging help with. Copy-paste the exact problematic code into your question.

Comment: @JoshCaswell those are default initializers from UIViewController that got inherited that is why I wasn't to worry about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class of the root view controller is set to YALFoldingTabBarController in Interface Builder an explicit initialization is not needed.

The Swift Equivalent of the ObjC line

```
YALFoldingTabBarController *tabBarController = (YALFoldingTabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;
```

is

```
let tabBarController = self.window.rootViewController as! YALFoldingTabBarController
```

Comment: thanks @vadian I will let you know if it works as soon as I try pretty sure it will!